# How to render a poll within a node?

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to embed a poll into the body of a node with PHP code:

```
$node = node_load(123);
print node_view($node, 'full');
```

That won't work. What's the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a node reference field to the content type you want to add a poll to, and choose the formatter that renders the referenced poll node (instead of rendering just a link). I must add that I never tried this with poll nodes, but I expect it to work just like it does with other nodes.

Comment: dang, it worked. That's really cool!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I am looking at the poll.module correctly, you would use `$node=poll_view($node, 'full')` instead of `node_view($node, 'full')` and then run that through `drupal_render()` to display it.  If that doesn't work, this is pulled from/based upon the latest poll block_view:

```
$poll = node_load($nid);
$poll = poll_block_latest_poll_view($poll);
```

and might format it a bit nicer for drupal_render().

Answer (score 0):

`$poll_node = node_load($poll_nid);`

`$poll_view = node_view($poll_node);`

to render the form use `echo render($poll_view['poll_view_voting']);`

to render the results use `echo render($poll_view['poll_view_results']);`