# Creating a poll inside a content type

Tags: nodes, polls

I need a poll inside my content types.

Sometimes the users create an article and like to create a poll directly into the node they created. They don't want to create an extra poll with no connection to the original article.

So how can I get the poll functionality inside a different content type?

Comment: D7 provides a Poll module by default. You can enable it.

Comment: I think I explained myself badly. I need to create multiple types of content they have in a field that allows to create a poll, as the content type module Poll.

Comment: Are you a site builder or a developer? Would you mind writing some line of code and having a lightweight module that does the job?

Answer (score 1):

*Possible solution 1*: The [Pollfield module](https://drupal.org/project/pollfield) seems to be a good starting point. This should do what you need for Drupal 6. However, it might not be a stable solution for Drupal 7.

*Possible solution 2*: It seems the [Poll Improved module](https://drupal.org/project/pollim) might be fit your requirements seeing that provides a field for polls. Though it also doesn't have a stable D7 release.

> They don't want to create an extra poll with no connection to the original article.

You can use references (or entityreference) to have your article nodes reference a poll node. Though that would require another step for your content creators.

Comment: Here is a similar question that has some answers advising to render the poll node reference field. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28020/how-to-render-a-poll-within-a-node/28031#28031

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

1. Add [reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field from Article node to Poll node,
2. Use [inline entity form](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) to allow users adding Polls when adding/editing Articles

Comment: This is not working. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2300601

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be to add some fields to content-type comments and use drupal chart to render the aggregated results as a pie chart or whatever...

- pros: rather simple solution, based on stable modules and core;
- cons: poor management.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a new content type**

Make sure you installed and enabled pollfield module correctly before you try to do the following.

1. Go to Administer->Content Management -> Content types -> Add Content type (system path: admin/content/types/add)
2. Enter a name: Poll
3. And a type: poll
4. Submission form settings -> change "Title" field label to “Question”
5. If you like, you can also change the label of the body field
6. The other settings can be left as they are
7. Save!
8. On the next screen (system path: admin/content/types) locate the Poll content type and click on its edit link.
9. Adding the actual pollfield: Locate the “Add” area to find “New field” -> Label: Poll, fieldname: poll, field type: pollfield, widget: leave as is-> SAVE
10. Pollfield settings: explained at [Pollfield book](https://www.drupal.org/node/608018)
    IMPORTANT: “Global settings”-> required (so that you cannot accidently create a poll node without an actual poll)
11. SAVE!

You have just created an independent content type for polls. You may customize it by adding other fields. Do not forget that you can control the display settings at system path: admin/content/node-type/poll/display.